# How to use `Ctrl+c` in Nvim if GNOME terminal SIGINT call was remapped to Ctrl+x?

Tags: neovim, terminal, cut-copy-paste, linux

GNOME terminal SIGINT call was remapped to ctrl+x using `stty intr ^X`, and ctrl+c was mapped to be 'copy'. In Neovim config I have `vim.keymap.set("v", "<C-c>", "\"+y", { noremap = true })` to be able to copy in nvim using ctrl+c. So now because of GNOME terminal remaps, copy in nvim with ctrl+c is broken. But what is interesting: copy in nvim now works with shift+ctrl+c. How can I deal with it? I had the same problem with tmux and fixed it by: `bind-key -n C-x send-keys C-c` in tmux config. Now I think I need fix something in Nvim config.